# React does not see the value of the variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When the input is onChange, I want the value of the variable to change and be written to the console. But when changed it writes undefined to the console. Can you help me please ?

```
import './App.css';
import React,{useState,useEffect} from 'react';

function App() {
    let [message,setMessage] = useState("");
    
    useEffect((message) => {
    console.log(message);

    },[message])
return(
<div> 
    <input type="text" onChange={e => setMessage(e.target.value)}  />
</div>

)}
export default App;
```

[Why does it say undefined every time there is an onchange?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSeMC.png)

Comment: So when we use useEffect, we can't give parameters?

Comment: The `useEffect` hook callback isn't passed any argument, so the value of `message` in the callback is undefined. Just remove `message` as a function arg and reference the `message` state that is closed over in callback scope. Voting to close as "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo".

Answer (score 2):

The issue is, that you wrote

```
useEffect((message) => {
    console.log(message);
},[message])
```

but it should be like this

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log(message);
},[message])
```

Comment: So when we use useEffect, we can't give parameters?

Comment: why do you need to have parameters there? You usually take values from useState. You use useEffect, when you expect the values from for example useState to change and based on this change, the useEffect will fire and do something.

Comment: Yes, as you said, there is no need to send parameters, but when there was a problem, it caught my attention, I wanted to ask when I couldn't find the solution, thank you very much for your interest

Answer (score 0):

It is because you declare `message` to useEffect as an argument in the callback function and that is a different message than the state, it is local to the useEffect.

You need to write

```
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(message);

    },[message])
```

Comment: So when we use useEffect, we can only define a local variable for the parameter, we can't give any external variables, am I right? thank you for answering

Comment: Exactly, useEffect doesn't accept parameters. All you need is already available in the state variable. To be fair, useEffect accepts parameters, a callback function and an array of dependencies. The callback function is the one that doesn't accept parameters

Comment: If you have time, can I ask you one more question?

Comment: I want it to print the message to the console when clicked. When I use message as parameter it returns object instead of message. If I don't give it as a parameter, it's fine. Why does it convert it to an object when I give it as a parameter? Can't we give external parameter in Click event?

`
function App() {
    const [message,setMessage] = useState("");
    const add = (message) => {
        console.log(message);
    }
return(
<div> 
    <input type="text" onChange={e => setMessage(e.target.value)}  />
    <button onClick={add}>add</button>
</div>
)}
`

Comment: The onClick passes to `add` the event object, that is why and you rename it message so you essentialy printing the event object rather than the message from state. Do it like const add = (e) => {(console.log(message);}

Comment: Even though I wrote the code block between `` while commenting, it didn't turn it into a code structure, I hope you didn't have any trouble reading it. I'm new to this platform so I don't know much

Comment: Got it, it's printing the event object I renamed instead of my message variable. Thank you very much. You really helped me a lot. thanks again and again